# Can't connect to router behind other router from outside

Tags: router, adsl, dynamic-dns

I have the following setup:

> Internet ⟷ ADSL internet router ⟷ TP-LINK wireless router

I want to access this TP-LINK router through the internet. I've tried to access it by DynDNS or No-IP, but I always get to the ADSL router's configuration page, not the TP-LINK page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the DSL modem also acts as a router. It seems.
You could modify it's port forwarding, to this:
 IP: IP of your router
Incoming port: 12345
Port inside: 80

If there is no way to set the DSL's ports, try installing a custom firmware to your router, and set the web UI to a different port. :81 for example. (DD-WRT, OpenWRT can do this for example.)

Again. This only works if you can reach the machines/things inside behind your router. If you can't, you won't get past the DSL modem.

Comment: look my friend i can access the dsl router but what about incoming and inside port